# Stop OnDrag callback when user's finger is stationary?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

There's an section of the documentation that [refers to something that may be the answer](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/2018.4/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData-dragging.html), but unfortunately, if I keep holding with my finger the draggable object, even when I'm not moving my finger, the boolean `draggin` keeps returning `true`. This may be by design, but what I want is to stop the OnDrag callback when my finger is stationary. I imaged that there MUST be a variable/method that I can use for that, so I found `IsPointerMoving()`, but it works pretty much the same way as `draggin`. It always returns `true`.

So, knowing that I'm using the IDragHandler interface, how can I check, using the eventData parameter, if the pointer is stationary?

Comment: Presumably you considered checking whether `delta` is within a small tolerance, or comparing the current pointer position against a cached one? Were these unsuitable for your needs for some reason?

Comment: Hmmm, so you mean a timer? Like, if delta hasn't move in x amount of time then stop the movement?  Makes sense, though the threshold value would requiere a huge amount of fine tuning...

Comment: I made no mention of a timer. And yes, game input & control systems generally require fine tuning for feel.